# JScrollPane always clears my Panel

Tags: java, panel, jscrollpane, repaint

Hy.. I have a JPanel, and in this contentPanel I added some other custom panels and give them locations etc. So now I added a JScrollPane to the contentPanel and always when I scroll down it clears my contentPanel, but the panels are still there but not visible...

How can I make them visible again?

That's my code to add the Panel into the contentPanel. The x,y,j are some settingsstuff for the location because I have an fixed window.

```
private void reloadContentPanel() {

    int x = -200, y = 0, j = 1, row = 4;
    EventPanel panel = null;

    int i;
    for(i=0; i < this.images.size();i++)
    {
        panel = new EventPanel(this.images.get(i).getAbsolutePath(), 
                               this.images.get(i).getName());

        panel.setLocation(x+(j*200), y);
        j++;
        if(i == row) {
            x = -200;
            y += 205;
            j = 1;
            row += 5;
        }
        this.contentPanel.add(panel);
    }
    this.repaint();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: "If code needed, pls post it!" you should post yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer! :)

I use a GridLayout not a FlowLayout, so it's fine and it automatically refreshes the panels =)

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you are not using a LayoutManager correctly.

after creating your JFrame (i'm guessing within your constructor) add the following (for example):

```
this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

this will certainly not be the best layout manager for what you are trying to do but will stop the `add` calls from overriding the displayed component.

you will need to read further about [LayoutManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)s

besides this, it's not really advisable to extend JFrame. It's better practice to treat JFrame as a member of your class just like all the other components.

Comment: You think if I set the Layout to FlowLayout it will add my panels automatically in the right position? I tried it and the panels are in the same position like the first. (overlapped)